# exact preg_match with #

Tags: php, preg-match

How can I `preg_match` exactly with that kind of search:

- My value to find: `#5#`
- My value to search: `#5#;#9#`

I did a simple

```
if (preg_match("#5#", "#5#;#9#")) { return true; } else { return false; }
```

And, it returns true.

The problem with that code, it's return also true if my value to compare is `#51#;#55#` whereas it has to be false in that case:

```
if (preg_match("#5#", "#51#;#55#")) { return true; } else { return false; }
```

Also returns true whereas I want false.

Comment: Use preg_match_all()

Comment: preg_match_all("/#5#/",$value)

Comment: ok that simple ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match("#5#", "#51#;#55#")` returns true because preg_match uses `#` as delimiter. In order to match `#5#` you have to add delimiters around the regex:

```
if (preg_match("/#5#/", "#51#;#55#")) { return true; } else { return false; }
```

This will return false.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to find a string you know (`#5#`) in another string then the best way is to use function [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). It returns the boolean `FALSE` if it cannot find the string or an integer number that represents the position of the searched string into the other string.

It is faster that any `preg_*()` function.

```
$pos = strpos('#5#', '#5#;#9#');
if ($pos !== FALSE) {
    echo('Found (at position '.$pos.')');
} else {
    echo('Not found.');
}
```

You have to pay attention to the comparison operator: using `$pos != FALSE` is not enough because [`0 == FALSE`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). You have to compare using `===` or `!==` to avoid this.

#### Using `preg_match()`

Your approach failed because in PHP the [`PCRE`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) functions interpret the first character from the `regex` as a [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

This means the `regex` in `#5#` is: `5`. And this `regex`, of course, matches any `5` it finds in the string. To fix it you have to surround your `regex` with some delimiter (`/` is usually used):

```
return preg_match('/#5#/', '#5#;#9#');
```